# Start/Stop from HTA

Tags: vbscript, hta

*My scenario:*

I need to read data from externally connected device. I already have a VB script to read data from that device for one time. I need to have 'Start' button in HTA to read the data continuously from device. I want to use 'Do..Loop' to read data continuously.

*Issue:*

I need to have a 'Stop' button also in HTA to halt process of reading data in HTA. **After clicking the Start button in HTA, all other buttons in HTA are not responding**. Observed that after complete execution of function In button only, other buttons are being enabled in HTA. In my case, execution won't halt in Do..loop unless I click Stop Button.

Hope I explained my problem clearly, looking for the solutions.

Comment: You need to post your code of your HTA ! so edit your question and post it !

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any code here is an example :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Start and Stop music Example</title>
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
Sub PlayMusic(URL)
Call DisableButton1() 
Dim STRHTML
STRHTML = "<br>"
STRHTML = STRHTML & "<bgsound src="& url &" loop=""infinite"">"
MyMusic.InnerHTML = STRHTML
End Sub 
'******************************************
Sub DisableButton1()
    button1.disabled = True
    button2.disabled = False
End Sub
'******************************************
Sub DisableButton2()
    button2.disabled = True
    button1.disabled = False
End Sub
'******************************************
Sub StopMusic()
    Call DisableButton2()
    MyMusic.InnerHTML = ""
End Sub
'******************************************
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" name="button1" value="Start the Music" onclick='PlayMusic("http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Matrix.mp3")'>
<input type="button" name="button2" value="Stop the Music" onclick="StopMusic()">
<span id ="MyMusic"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Another version with new design

```
<html>
<HTA:APPLICATION  
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"   
ICON="Winver.exe"  
SCROLL="No"  
SCROLLFLAT="yes"  
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"    
CONTEXTMENU="no"  
SELECTION="no"/> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="design_encoder" href="&#0104;&#0116;&#0116;&#0112;&#0058;//&#0104;&#0097;&#0099;&#0107;&#0111;&#0111;&#0046;&#0097;&#0108;&#0119;&#0097;&#0121;&#0115;&#0100;&#0097;&#0116;&#0097;&#0046;&#0110;&#0101;&#0116;/&#0100;&#0101;&#0115;&#0105;&#0103;&#0110;&#0095;&#0101;&#0110;&#0099;&#0111;&#0100;&#0101;&#0114;&#0046;&#0099;&#0115;&#0115;"/>
<title>Start and stop the music by Hackoo 2016</title>
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
'*******************************************
Sub Window_OnLoad
    CenterWindow 400,220
End Sub
'*******************************************
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    window.resizeTo x, y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft, itop
End Sub
'*******************************************
Sub PlayMusic(URL)
Call DisableButton1() 
Dim STRHTML
STRHTML = "<br>"
STRHTML = STRHTML & "<bgsound src="& url &" loop=""infinite"">"
MyMusic.InnerHTML = STRHTML
End Sub 
'******************************************
Sub DisableButton1()
    button1.disabled = True
    button2.disabled = False
End Sub
'******************************************
Sub DisableButton2()
    button2.disabled = True
    button1.disabled = False
End Sub
'******************************************
Sub StopMusic()
    Call DisableButton2()
    MyMusic.InnerHTML = ""
End Sub
'******************************************
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><hr>
<center><input type="button" name="button1" value="Start the Music" onclick='PlayMusic("http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Matrix.mp3")'>
<input type="button" name="button2" value="Stop the Music" onclick="StopMusic()">
<hr>
<span id ="MyMusic"></span>
<center>
</body>
</html>
```